# Index of maximal proper subgroup of a solvable group

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

This is problem 2.7.15 from Hungerford's *Algebra*:

> If $H$ is a maximal proper subgroup of a finite solvable group $G$, then $[G:H]$ is a prime power.

If $G$ is abelian, then it's easy to show that $[G:H]$ is a prime power. I'm stuck on the non-abelian case. Any hints how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a solvable group, you can show that a minimal normal subgroup is abelian of prime power order. I think this is a lemma in Hungerford that is proven in the section this problem is in.

Now here's a hint for your problem. Proceed by induction, and let $N \neq 1$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Consider the cases $N \leq H$ and $N \not\leq H$ separately.

Comment: Thanks! It's lemma 2.7.13. I'll see where that takes me.

Comment: Where is induction being used here?

Comment: @wasatar: In the case where $N \leq H$, we note that $H/N$ is a maximal subgroup of $G/N$ and apply induction on $G/N$.

Comment: @wasatar: Base case is $|G| = 1$. In the induction step, we use strong induction. That is, we assume that the result holds groups of order $< |G|$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen Oh I see now, since N is not trivial |G/N| < |G| and we can get the result. Thanks for clearing that up!